# What kinds of external Hard drives are compatible with PS5?

Tags: ps4, hard-drive, ps5

I'm looking to see if anyone knows off hand types of external HDs to look for specifically for PS5/PS4.

Answer (score 1):

Any USB plug and play hard drive is fine, the PS5/PS4 will reformat the external hard drive so it's usable. This is not the case with the secondary SSD slot for the PS5.

Answer (score 1):

The information below is taken from [PS5 Extended Storage](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/hardware/ps5-extended-storage/) and [PS4 Extended Storage](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/hardware/ps4-external-hdd-support/). The requirements are roughly the same, which a few differences. While the information provides a good overall view on what is supported, it is best to research the harddrive to ensure it is compatible:

- **Space** - The harddrive capacity must be between 250Gb and 8TB
- **USB** - The harddrive must support USB 3.0. The information below is a combination of both articles:

  - SuperSpeed USB 5 Gbps (USB 3.0/USB 3.1 Gen1/USB 3.2 Gen1)
  - SuperSpeed USB 10 Gbps (USB 3.1 Gen2/USB 3.2 Gen2/USB 3.2 Gen1x2)

    - (PS5 ONLY) USB 3.2 Gen1x2 devices are supported but as single-lane USB3.2 x1 connections (5Gbps)
  - SuperSpeed USB 20 Gbps (USB 3.2 Gen2x2)

    - (PS5 ONLY) USB 3.2 Gen2x2 devices are supported but as single-lane USB3.2 x1 connections (10Gbps).

Other general information on the articles state:

- PS4 - "Proper operation is not guaranteed for all external hard disc drive models."
- PS5 - "Not all devices are guaranteed to work with the PS5 console"